# Using Openpyxl in python, after setting font to all cells in a column, update a cell in the column and the cell won't get the column's font?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

So as seen in the code below, all cells in column A get the font style 'italic24Font' except for cell 'A1'.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Font

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb["Sheet"]
italic24Font = Font( size = 24, italic = True )
column = sheet.column_dimensions['A']
column.font = italic24Font
sheet['A1'] = 'Hello world'
wb.save( 'test.xlsx' )
```

Comment: This is covered in the documentation http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5/styles.html#applying-styles

Comment: Yes, you are right. Guess it is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like when you write to a cell the column settings gets reset to default.

You can set the font to the column as you write content to the cell

**EX:**

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Font

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb["Sheet"]
italic24Font = Font( size = 24, italic = True, color='00FF0000' )
column = sheet.column_dimensions['A']
column.font = italic24Font

sheet['A1'] = 'Hello world'
sheet['A1'].font = italic24Font
wb.save( 'test.xlsx' )

print "Done!!!"
```

I had the same issue. Not sure if it is a bug with openpyxl

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you "when you write to a cell the column settings gets reset to default". Maybe it's a bug in openpyxl.